# Does MySQL (MyISAM) fill table holes in a multirow insert?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, auto-increment

I'm working on a project for which I need to frequently insert ~500 or so records at a remote location. I will be doing this in a single `INSERT` to minimize network traffic. I do, however, need to know the exact `id` field (`AUTO_INCREMENT`) values.

My web searches seem to indicate I could probably use the `last_insert_id` and calculate all the id values from there. However, this wouldn't work if the rows get ids that are all over the place.

Could anyone please clarify what would or should happen, and if the mathematical solution is safe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A multirow insert is an atomic operation in MySQL (both MyISAM and InnoDB). Since the table will be locked for writing during this operations, no other rows will be inserted/updated during it's execution.

This means IDs will in fact be consecutive (unless [auto-increment-increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) option is set to something different than 1

Comment: Is this safe for InnoDB? It was my understanding that it wouldn't be... (although I could be, and probably am, wrong)

Comment: (lol @ cross commenting). Yes it is safe, and I actually tested that. Remember that be default each InnoDB operation runs within a separate transacrtion, so for two insert statements that start one after another, the AUTO_INCREMENT value of table is the same until one of them is commited.

Comment: In fact row-level locking is only relevant for updates/replaces/deletes. Inserts are still queued.

Answer (score 1):

Auto increment does exactly that, it auto-increments - i.e. each new row next the numerically next ID. MySQL does not re-use IDs of rows that were deleted.

Your solution is safe because write operations aquire a table lock, so no other inserts can happen while your operation completes - so you will get `n` contiguous auto-increment values for `n` inserted rows.

Comment: @Mchl Fair enough, I will edit my answer. I thought this was related to the fact that auto-increment behaves differently for MyISAM and InnoDB - if you create a primary key that spans two columns, and one is AI, MyISAM will consider both columns when choosing an AI value (so the same AI value may appear more than once), whereas InnoDB will not.

Comment: Yeah, it's worth knowing ins and outs of auto increments, so that they don't kick you in the back side when least expected ;)

Comment: @Mchl ...indeed, I have learnt something about it there and you deserve this tasty +1 I shall bestow upon you.

Comment: Heh, thanks :). +1 to you too for discussion that extended the topic a bit.